# automapper add every map source and destination to dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, automapper

I have a model and a view model

```
public class CategoryViewModel{
    public string Serial { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
}

public class Category{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public Category Parent { get; set; }
}
```

and the `CategoryViewModel` is in treeview shape. I want to map `CategoryViewModel` to `Category` with `Automapper` and also add them to a dictionary as mentioned below:

```
Dictionary<string, OrganizationLevel> dic = new Dictionary<string, OrganizationLevel>();
```

Also, I want ot get the source view model `serial` as key and destination `Category` as value then add them to dictionary something like this:

```
automapper.map<CategoryViewModel, Category>({
   config =>{ dic.add( categoryViewModel.serial, category ) }
},categoryViewmodelTree)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in mapper config add:

```
AfterMap((src, des) => dic.Add(src, des));
```